# jqModal and live querying (R14)

Tags: jquery, jqmodal

I have a dynamically created table that I am trying to attach a modal effect when an image is clicked and am having trouble.  Since the rows in the table are dynamic, I am using the "live" feature.  The first time that the user clicks on the image, the modal pops up fine, but on the next click it does not work.  I thought that with jqModal all attempts to reinitialize jqm after the first initialization would just update the parameters.  The error that I am getting is $("#divModal").jqm is not a function

Here is the code that I have so far

```
<'img link=add_product.php?id=X src=./images/icons/pencil.png class=img_pencil id=imgPencil_'.$aRow['product_id'].'>

$(".img_pencil").live("click", function(){
    $('#divModal').jqm({ajax: 'add_product.php?id=XXXX'});
    $('#divModal').jqmShow();
    return false; // have tried with and without this
});
```

I have also tried to pass the link using $('#jqModal').jqm({ajax:'@href'}), but nothing happens when I tried that.

Any ideas?  I hope I am clear enough in my explanation of my problem....

Answer (score 0):

The way that I got my live query to work, it I split up the assignment and event, IE.

```
$('#divModal').jqm({ajax: 'add_product.php?id=XXXX'});

$(".img_pencil").live("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();  
    $('#divModal').jqmShow(this);
});
```